# Deployable bootable USB image?

Tags: linux, live-usb

I'm trying to create a very lightweight server stack (this is for Ethereum mining so think single application + dependencies) that can be quickly and easily imaged onto a flash-drive and just booted to, not unlike a LiveCD. This is because I may need to deploy many of these.

To be clear I'm not talking about a custom installer. I want this to boot directly into the OS, treating the USB stick just like a hard drive.

Ideally I'd have an easy way to convert a live OS to an ISO so that a tool like Rufus could be used to create USB drives.

So far I've almost got it. I've installed Ubuntu Server onto one of the machines (one of the USB drives to be exact) and setup the needed software. I then use gparted to copy over the primary partition (no swap setup) to a new drive, resize and a couple of commands to reinstall GRUB.

That doesn't produce the wanted ISO though, it's a much more manual process.

SO my question is how would one go about creating such an image since I know it can be done, that's what LiveCD's basically are.